# BNFC to Define Boolean Token

Tags: grammar, bnfc

I am trying to write a parser with BNF Converter. The grammar that I am using allows things like `a ::= true` and `b ::= false`. So I'm trying to create a token to accomplish this. This is what I have so far:

```
token BVAL ("true"|"false");
```

I'm hoping to use it like this:

```
Exp ::= BVAL "||" BVAL
```

When I try and run BNFC I get the below error:

```
user error (syntax error at line 1 before true | false ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [BNFC reference manual](http://bnfc.digitalgrammars.com/LBNF-report.pdf), the way you write a sequence of characters in a `token` rule is, for example, `{"true"}` rather than `"true"`. (See section 5.1, "The `token` rule", on page 5.)